# Detecting the escape key using the shortKeys plugin for jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have all other keys set up using shortKeys in JavaScript like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://rikrikrik.com/js/jquery.shortkeys.js"></script>

$(document).shortkeys({
'U':       function () {
    $('#imginput').slideToggle(500);
    $("#textinput").slideUp(500);
    $("#sortPost").slideUp(500);
}});
```

Now I am trying to set up the escape key, but I dont know how.

I tried:

```
$(document).shortkeys({
'Esc':       function () {
    $('#imginput').slideUp(500);
    $("#textinput").slideUp(500);
    $("#sortPost").slideUp(500);
    $('.help_info').fadeOut(500);
}});
```

and I also tried:

```
e.keyCode == 27:       function () {
    $('#imginput').slideUp(500);
    $("#textinput").slideUp(500);
    $("#sortPost").slideUp(500);
    $('.help_info').fadeOut(500);
}});
```

How would I make it so that these events occur when I press escape?

Comment: It should probably be `27` instead of `e.keyCode == 27`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know `shortkeys` but using a standard `keyup` binding you can do this:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 27) {
        $('#imginput').slideUp(500);
        $("#textinput").slideUp(500);
        $("#sortPost").slideUp(500);
        $('.help_info').fadeOut(500);
    }
});​
```

As noted in the `event.which` [**documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/):

> The event.which property normalizes event.keyCode and event.charCode.
>   It is recommended to watch event.which for keyboard key input.